# How do I know which command serverless uses to build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a nodejs application and use `serverless` to manage AWS infra for lambda and API Gateway. I use the command `serverless deploy` to deploy to AWS. There is a `.serverless` folder created by this command which includes a zip file of my code and `node_modules`. I was wondering which command `serverless` uses to build the code and install the dependencies. Can I change the command it uses?

Comment: interesting question, what is the goal you have?  You always have https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-scripts where you can add some scripts

Comment: I seems like a hook command. I'd like to replace the command `serverless` use. Like run `npm install --production`